# Undefined reference error in C using Code::Blocks IDE

Tags: c, reference, undefined, codeblocks

I'm trying to set up some .c files to make it easier on me to find things, once it starts becoming larger. I'll be using SDL calls in the program, hence the includes.

Here's how my main.cpp looks right now:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_gfxPrimitives.h>
#include <SDL_ttf.h>
#include "WriteText.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int i =0;
i = b();

return 0;
}
```

In my WriteText.c I have:

```
#include "WriteText.h"

int b(void)
{
return 3;
}
```

Finally my WriteText.h:

```
#ifndef WRITETEXT_H_INCLUDED
#define WRITETEXT_H_INCLUDED

int b(void);

#endif // WRITETEXT_H_INCLUDED
```

Trying to compile it, I get an undefined reference to 'b()'. I have no idea why this is happening, I practiced it in some basic example codes and everythin works just fine, but as soon as I'd actually use it for something practical I hit an error like this.

Comment: Are you certain that this is a *complete* example?

Comment: How are you compiling this? Specifically, is `WriteText.c` actually being built/linked?

Comment: Do you link `WriteText.o` and `main.o` together?

Comment: I'm using Codeblocks with GNU GCC compiler, it's a veeery basic example but apart from doing nothing, it should work.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are not linking the `WriteText.c` into your executable. If you gave some more information about how you are creating the executable we could probably give better help.

Comment: Sorry, completely forgot about adding detail. I'm using Codeblocks with the GNU GCC Compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are your compilation isn't using the writetext object file.  Assuming *nix and gcc, your makefile should look something like:

```
all: myprog

myprog: myprog.o writetext.o
    gcc -o $@ $^

myprog.o: myprog.cpp

writetext.o: writetext.cpp
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my issue, my main file was .cpp and used CPP compiler (because it was an SDL project), but the new file I added was .c and used C compiler, when I added a new .cpp file and just copy-pasted my code into it, everything worked smoothly.

(I'm not sure if it's "bad form" to write C code in .cpp files but if I intend to use SDL I guess that's the only way to go.)